# Crash in CBPeripheral writeValue: forDescriptor:

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

After establishing a connection with a TI BLE Keyfob and retrieving the descriptors for a characteristic, I attempt the call

```
   [peripheral writeValue: nsData forDescriptor: descriptor];
```

The various objects look reasonable in the debugger. nsData has a single byte of 1, peripheral is a valid looking CBPeripheral object returned from iOS, and descriptor is a valid looking CBDescriptor returned by iOS.

My app crashes with the error

> *** Assertion failure in -[CBConcretePeripheral writeValue:forDescriptor:],
>   /SourceCache/CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth-59.3/CBConcretePeripheral.m:358

Any thoughts on why this is happening or how to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Note from the documentation of `writeValue:forDescriptor`

> Client characteristic configuration descriptors cannot be written
>   using this method, and should instead use `setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:`

So if you are trying to write the descriptor of the connected peripheral, then it will fail.

For writing the characteristic, use the `- writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:` method.